# Server certificate vs Client Certificate

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, ssl

I'm using a Winforms client to connect to a WCF service hosted in IIS. The Winforms application will be available to customers to download and install on their computers. The customers have to login to the application using their username/passwords. I want a secure HTTPS enabled communication between the client application and the WCF. What is the best practice to provide such a functionality? Should I use client certificates or just a server certificate? Any input is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a server certificate.

If you want stronger authentication you can use client certificates. There is an administration of certificates overhead and potentially other costs to that though: Using certificates from a provider, generating them yourself, maintaining list of revocations and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I choose to use client certificates, they should be installed beforehand on customers' computers or is there a way we can install the certificate when they install the application? Also do we need multiple certificates for each customer?

Comment: That can be a little complicated. Basic answer is you can't because they need to have the corresponding private key. At the same time you can if, for example, run your own CA and generate them as the application fist starts (or during installation) and have a few identity checks (e.g. user is handed a secret string and they have to call a certain number and verify their identity in some way or send them another secret over SMS and so on). It can get complicated. Another option is to check already established CAs to see if they have any tools to help you with this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

As you already authenticate the user with password, client certificate authentication is not needed. To ensure the communication is secured use a self-signed server certificate. In case if the clients needs to verify that they are connecting to the correct server then you need to get a signed certificate from a third party CA like verisign which could cost you atleast 100$.